# Python - Issue when writing data to file when running

Tags: python, data-storage

I am reasonably new to Python and creating a GUI registration system, for a small quiz I am creating as part of a project. When storing the data of the playername + as small string to a text document, I am getting a few problems, here are what I am unsure on, and what I cannot get to fix:

- A notepad document is created in the name of the user who has registered, but the the data that is required to be entered is not, and the document is left blank.
- Although including if and else statements when writing into the file an error window is still displayed which is supposed to only display when the text file already exists.

Thanks for the help you may give, I really appreciate it, and have a great day! 
- Jam

---

The code:

```
__author__ = 'Jamie'

# Imports all from Tkinter and imports os.path
from tkinter import *
import os.path
import tkinter.messagebox


# Creates module to run the game
def runGame():
    from pythonDocs import mainGame
    mainGame()


def Details():
    # Creates window
    startGUI = Tk()
    startGUI.geometry("270x250")
    startGUI.title("Python Challenge")

    # Creates text for startScreen
    Label(startGUI, text="Please enter your details:").grid(row=0)
    Label(startGUI, text="Please enter your Username (e.g. Jam40e)").grid(row=2)
    Label(startGUI, text="Please enter your Email (e.g. help@support.com)").grid(row=4)
    Label(startGUI, text="Please enter your Age (In numbers)").grid(row=6)
    Label(startGUI, text="Please enter your Gender (Male or Female)").grid(row=8)

    # Setting global variables
    global e1
    global e2
    global e3
    global e4


    # Creates entry field for details
    e1= Entry(startGUI)
    e1.grid(row=3, column=0)
    e1.focus_set()

    e2 = Entry(startGUI)
    e2.grid(row=5, column=0)
    e2.focus_set()

    e3 = Entry(startGUI)
    e3.grid(row=7, column=0)
    e3.focus_set()

    e4 = Entry(startGUI)
    e4.grid(row=9, column=0)
    e4.focus_set()

    def printtext():
        string = e1.get()
        string1 = e2.get()
        string2 = e3.get()
        string3 = e4.get()

        # Creates filePath
        PATH='./playerdata/' + string + '.txt'

        # Opens some text files to be writen on
        text_file_exists = open ('./playerdata/' + string + '.txt ' , 'w')
        text_file = open ('./playerdata/' + string + '.txt ' , 'w')
        if os.path.exists (PATH):
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('ERROR!','This username is already in use!')
        else:
            text_file.write (string + ', ADDSCORE')
            text_file.close()
    # Create entry button
    startButton3 = Button(text="Enter!", width=10, fg = 'green', activeforeground ='red', command = lambda: printtext())
    startButton3.grid(row=11, column=0)

 # Waits for input and draws window
    startGUI.mainloop()

Details()
```

Pasted in to a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/8gXc6L1x

Comment: Try deleting that `text_file_exists =` line, since it doesn't seem to do anything. And IIRC, opening a file twice can cause weird behavior.

Comment: Wait, you open a file, and then you ask the OS if it exists?

Comment: My IDE automatically removes that line. But I have removed it anyway. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Fixed it, it was my own stupid fault. Thanks @NightShadeQueen I didn't notice that! xD

Comment: Happens to everyone :P

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NightShadeQueen I have realised that I attempt to create the document and then check if it exists, silly me! Thanks for the answers.